# Laravel pagination in Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel-query-builder, laravel-6, laravel-pagination

I need help to paginate a table that has a relationship with another using Laravel pagination. I get an error that says...

> too fewer argument to function

**Controller**

```php
public function users()
{
    $users = User::join('customers', 'users.id', '=', 'customers.user_id')
        ->select('customers.*')->orderBy('customers.name', 'asc')
        ->paginate(2);

    return view('paginate', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

**View**

```php
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($users->customers() as $customer)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->location}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->age}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$users->customers()->links()}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/frontend_js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/frontend_js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

**Relationship** (between the two tables)

```php
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer')->paginate(2);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: "It shows error" - what, where? Add comment in code at least.

Comment: @zydnar the table has relationship that is the point.the web page where i want to paginate does not show.the page shows error that "too fewer argument to function".there is no way i am not going to use relationship, the table has relationship with another table

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
{{$users->customers()->links()}}
```

with this

```
{{$users->links()}}
```

Remove `pagination` from this relation.

```
public function customers(){

       return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');
    }
```